# Change labels text with javascript and read it from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with a label on it. The label has no text.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

At some point, I call a `javascript` function that adds some content to the label, as follows:

```
function myFunc() { 
                label = document.getElementById("Label1");
                list = document.getElementById("list");
                label.innerHTML = list.innerText;
            }
```

*After* that function is done, I click a button on the page, that calls its `onclick` event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Label1.Text;
    }
```

For some reason, the `Label1.Text` is still empty. Why? Is there any way I could fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value doesn't get posted to the code-behind.

No matter how much WebForms tries to hide this, the only data that gets posted from a web page to the server is data that's in `form` elements.  What WebForms does with things like label texts is stuff them into an `input type="hidden"` as one big serialized base-64 encoded string.  (It calls this "view state" but it's really just a hidden `form` element.)

Changing the page markup doesn't change anything server-side because page markup isn't posted to the server.

What you *can* do is create a form element and change that along with the markup.  Something as simple as:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hidden1" />
```

Whenever you change the markup in JavaScript, also change that value:

```
label = document.getElementById("Label1");
hidden = document.getElementById("Hidden1");
list = document.getElementById("list");
label.innerHTML = list.innerText;
hidden.value = list.innerText;
```

*This* will be posted back to the server, since it's a `form` element.  Then you can access the value server-side:

```
string a = Hidden1.Value;
```

Comment: hi @David and Michael could you please answer this quetions <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797625/need-to-access-update-label-value-from-javascript-to-my-code-behind-in-asp-net-c>  and  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723662/how-to-calculate-number-of-views-to-post-in-asp-net-c-sharp-and-mysql-database> . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ID="Label1"` for ASP.NET is server side, but for javascript we need a client side ID ie `"<%=Label1.ClientID%>"`